# Creating a chat layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I attempted to create a android chat layout in xml, but I could not get things how I wanted. This is the closest I could get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="10"  >
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/text" 
            android:id="@+id/textOutput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="true">
        <EditText android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textInput"
            android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Send"
            android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This results in [this](http://gyazo.com/88a7e7a07fabf305e969626c8c590687).
The problem with this layout (which is pretty messy), is that I don't want the size of the lower LinearLayout to be a percentage. I want it to be a fixed height, and the TextView in the ScrollView(is this the best way to make large text scroll?) to fill up the rest of the screen. I must be missing some attribute or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try not giving the bottom section a weight, but just wrap content, then have the top scroll fill remaining space by giving it a weight of 1. Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1"  >
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/text" 
            android:id="@+id/textOutput"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="true">
        <EditText android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textInput"
            android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="0dip">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="Send"
            android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask what the 0dip means? Is it the same as 0dp?

Comment: I believe it means the same thing to Android. The only important thing about using that value, is that its an efficiency hack for the layout logic. It's used to tell Android that its this value to perform the weighting on (width or height). Not a huge deal, just use any scale that would translate into 0!