# Android chat application-xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, client-server, chat

I am making a chat application for Android. How should be the chat screen? Can anyone tell me what all views should I use in XML layout? Is it an edittext and a listview? Pls help. I need to make a chat screen like the one we see in Gtalk. The chat messages of both persons should be aligned to opposite sides of the screen(see Gtalk chat box align style).this is what I want..How can I implement this layout?
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Google_talk.gif

Comment: @raghav sood I could retrieve user details from server,but  I don't know how to display chat messages of both the persons in conversation. Do I need single listview, an edittext and a submit button or textviews and edittext and button? that's my doubt

Comment: I suggest you to go read some tutorial about adapters, try to implement the tutorial, and after that, if you having problems in some specific point, come back and ask.

Comment: @Budis I did all those things. Still I am confused which way is better, please suggest one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a chat layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327826/creating-a-chat-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the suitable one. So I am sharing it here

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1"  >
    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/text" 
        android:id="@+id/textOutput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:paddingRight="5dp" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:baselineAligned="true">
    <EditText android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="0dip">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <Button android:text="Send"
        android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out some tutorials about recycler view and adapters. You can create two viewholders one for sent messages and other for received messages and inflate them according to the type of message.

This link gives an example on how to create a chat UI.
https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui